# Parsing table elements with Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to parse data from [this table](https://www.easistent.com/urniki/cc45c5d0d303f954588402a186f5cdba5edb51d6/razredi/16515). Let's say, for example, that I want to parse the second elements from the second row (called SLO).

[image]

I can see there is a TR inside TR and the SLO word doesn't even have an ID or anything. How can I parse this?

This is the code:

```
class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        tw1.setText("Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.easistent.com/urniki/cc45c5d0d303f954588402a186f5cdba5edb51d6/razredi/16515").get();
                Elements eles = doc.select("");
                title = eles.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tw1.setText(title);
    }

}
```

I don't know what to put in the doc.select(""); because I've never parsed something like this. I've only parsed titles of webpages and such. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is plenty of information there for you to use, for example class names or title attributes. The URL you provided won't work for me, and I can't copy paste the HTML from your image so my example will show just the parsing of the span based on its title:

```
String html = "<span title='Slovenscina'>SLO</span>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements eles = doc.select("span[title=Slovenscina]");
String title = eles.text();
System.out.println(title);
```

Will output:

```
SLO
```

This will work in the scope of the other HTML that you provided. I suggest you read some more about the [selector-syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) of Jsoup.

Comment: ye he is very correct or directly from the site do   **Elements eles = doc.select(".text14 span[title=Slovenščina]:first");**